# how find the connecting words in text analysis in python?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I wanted to check the connection between 2 words in text analytics in python.currently using NLTK package in python.

For example
`"Text = "`There are thousands of types of specific networks proposed by researchers as modifications or tweaks to existing models"

here if i input as `networks` and `researchers`, then i should get output as
"Proposed by"
or "networks proposed by researchers"

Answer (score 1):

You could Regex match between the two words

```
import re

word_one = "networks"
word_two = "researchers"

string = "There are thousands of types of specific networks proposed by researchers as modifications or tweaks to existing models"

result = re.search(f'{word_one}(.+?){word_two}', string)
print(result.group(1))
```

Comment: Tom thanks for the code, but somehow its not working.There is error in the code.
 result = re.search(f'{word_one}(.+?){word_two}', string)
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

Tom's answer is cleaner. Here is my answer without additional libraries

Find the locations of each word, then use those locations to extract it

```
text = "There are thousands of types of specific networks proposed by researchers as modifications or tweaks to existing models"

word1 = "networks"
word2 = "researchers"

start = text.find(word1)
end = text.find(word2)

if start != -1 and end != -1 and start < end:
    print(text[start + len(word1):end])
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick , This is short and sweet.It worked perfectly as expected.